# Getting derived class from base method

Tags: c++, qt

I have 3 classes `Entity`, `Character` and `Item`.
When I do

```
Character * Player = new Character(QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50), "player", theScene);
Player->setVelocityX(30)->setAttackPoint(10);
```

The compiler tells that  `error: 'class Entity' has no member named 'setAttackPoint'`.
How can I make `Entity* setVelocityX(qreal vx);` return a `Character` pointer or an `Item` pointer?

.

```
class Entity : public QObject, public QGraphicsPolygonItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Entity();
        Entity(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h, QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Entity(QRectF position, QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Entity(QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Entity* setVelocityX(qreal vx);
        // etc
}


class Character : public Entity
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Character(qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h, QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Character(QRectF position, QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Character(QString tag, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
        Character* setAttackPoint(int attackPoint);
        //etc
}


class Item : public Entity
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        enum ItemType{
            Consummable,
            Special,
            Weapon
        };

        Item(QString name, qreal x, qreal y, qreal w, qreal h,  QString tag = "item", QGraphicsScene *scene = 0, Character *parent = 0);
        Item* setOwner(Character* newOwner);
        //etc
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the methods implementations, I assume they simply return a "this". Is that necessary? Would it not be easier to simply make two calls in your example? `Player->setVelocityX(30);` and `Player->setAttackPoint(10);`

Comment: You might use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @Bowdzone, Yes they return `this`. I wanted to make it in one line like in `JavaScript`. (And I'm learning c++).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I've tried that but it breaks everything and I get lots of errors. I've even tried using `virtual` method but no success.

Comment: Such an approach seems not really useful to me. You need a pointer to the object to call the method so you don't need to return the pointer as it is already known at the time and place of the call.

Comment: @Bowdzone, The thing is I wanted to do something like `Player->setX(10)->setAttackPoint(10)->setDefencePoint(12);` instead of writing `Player->setX(10); Player->setAttackPoint(10); Player->setDefencePoint(12);`

Comment: It is a bit like http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html, but returning pointers instead of references, but I have the feeling that in combination with polymorphism, it creates more issues than it solves.  You could put all the functions as virtual in the base class, but that is not considered a good design.

Comment: If it bothers you so much, couldn't you just create a function like `Character::setAllPoints(int x, int attackPoint, int defencePoint)`?

Comment: @stefaanv, Yes like that. And yes I've had many issues. :/

Comment: @thuga, that's not a problem but I have more than these properties in the classes (10 in `Entity` and 11(which makes 21) in `Character`)

Comment: If the base-class doesn't know anything about the child-classes, then it's impossible. Maybe if you post a new question with your try with the CRTP we can help you fix that?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, How can I make the base class aware of the child class methods and properties? Creating them as empty one?
Okay I'll retry it.

Comment: I still think that writing it like you intend to do makes the code messy and difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Bowdzone, won't it make it more readable one line and smaller size of cpp file than different lines repeating the pointer's name?

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely certain on the type (otherwise use dynamic_cast and check the resulting pointer for non-nullptr):

```
reinterpret_cast< Character * >( Player->setVelocityX(30))->setAttackPoint(10)
```

Also, based on your code, couldn't you go instead or is the order of the function calls significant?

```
Player->setAttackPoint(10)->setVelocityX(30)
```

Comment: I love the way you reordered the chain !

Comment: Don't `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`!

Comment: This is actually answering the question, but I wouldn't want to program in systems where you have to reorder seemingly unrelated things just to get it working and the casting ruins the gain of having a clear chained setting of parameters.  So, as I already stated in the question-comments: more issues created than solved.

Comment: So I have to use `reinterpret_cast` or `dynamic_cast`(it works) every time (even in the middle of the method chaining)?

It's not very convenient to chain the method in an order of child to base and some depends on others.

Comment: Or have the base class offer a virtual method with the same signature that your derived class can override.  Ultimately, your base class does not know the methods owned only by your derived class, but your derived knows everything about the base.

Comment: That's what I was wondering if it was good practice to create empty virtual method only returning `this` and making the real methods in the derived class..

Comment: In my experience, I use the virtual method in the base and either make it pure virtual to force derived classes to implement the method or have it throw an exception.  If I find a derived class not needing that method, then it was never the proper candidate for polymorphism for my usage.  You would have to make the judgement on ease of use, practicality and style you will want to write and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
Character* player = new Character(QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50), "player", theScene);
dynamic_cast<Character*>(player->setVelocityX(30))->setAttackPoint(10);
```

By the way this method is not type safe. You need to add some controls.

Generally, **SETS** methods are used to set some value, not to return an object.

```
Character* player = new Character(QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50), "player", theScene);
Entity* playerEntity = player->setVelocityX(30);
Character* isCharacter = dynamic_cast<Character*>(playerEntity);
if(isCharacter) {
   isCharacter->setAttackPoint(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I wanted something where I write less code.
How would you do method chaining?

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way of achieving what you want to do:
**Curriously Recurring Template Pattern**

The basic idea is that the base class has a template parameter which is the derived class.
Then you implement a **non virtual function** in every derived class which can then be called using a static_cast like that (simplified class layout):

**Entity.h**:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class DERIVED_CLASS>
class Entity
{
public:
    void doStuff()
    {
        static_cast<DERIVED_CLASS*>(this)->doStuffDerived();
    }
};


class Character : public Entity<Character>
{
public:
    void doStuffDerived()
    {
        // implementation
        std::cout << "character\n";
    }
};


class Item : public Entity<Item>
{
public:

    void doStuffDerived()
    {
        // implementation
        std::cout << "item\n";
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "Entity.h"

int main()
{
    // Instantiate a n Item object
    Entity<Item> item;
    item.doStuff();
    // Instantiate a character object 
    Character character;
    character.doStuff();
}
```

With this method you actually do **not have the cost of a virtual function call** but can implement a different behavior for every implementation which is kinda like a virtual function (a good compiler can easily optimize this code to only a function call on the derived class).

And you also do not have to rely on a reinterpret_cast, which should also be prevented if possible.

Here are some more informations: [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: I've tried but I received `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before *` and `class 'Character' does not have any field named 'Entity'`(from derived constructor)

Comment: By the way, is it good practice to use virtual methods which only return `this`(in the base class) then the real function in the derived class?(I've tried it and it works)

Comment: @Xlander Can't really confirm that. If I just create a small new project with the classes in a header and try to instantiate an Item object, everything works like expected if I call the `doStuff()` function. I suggest you to try to break down your implementation and start building more a complex use case from that.

Comment: Ah ok. But will I be able to return(non-void) the object(or the pointer) calling the method to chain by using CRTP?

Comment: You can have multiple function prototypes implemented in the Entity class and just implement a special behavior in the derived classes. Sure if there is a function, which is only available in the derived class, then you almost always have the problem that you have to cast your generic Entity datatype to the derived e.g. Item datatype. However what you can do is that you change the `doStuff()` function to `DERIVED_CLASS* doStuff()` and return the `static_cast` this pointer. With that you have the ability to chain function calls (unless you don't have the `Entity<?>` known)

Comment: I've tried `Derived *Entity::setAttackPoint(int attackPoint){return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setAttackPoint(attackPoint);}` but I get `'template<class Derived> class Entity' used without template parameters` and `invalid use of 'this' in non-member function` and if I do `Derived *Entity<Derived>::setAttackPoint(int attackPoint){return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setAttackPoint(attackPoint);}` I get `class 'Character' does not have any field named 'Entity'`

Comment: The way I instantiate my object is the following: `Entity<Item> item; item.doStuff();`. You can also use the derived type like: `Item item;` and the call the function the same way. I will update my answer and add a sample main function for that...

Comment: Ok, thanks, If I do `Character character;
    character.doStuff();` what will be the output?

Comment: In my example it should print "character". In my small example project it worked :)

Comment: That's strange, when I do `Entity<Character> Player; Player.doStuff()` it worked, but doing `Character Player; Player.doStuff();` doesn't.

Comment: That is indeed a bit strange. Also note that you should always use the Character class directly for instantiation, since otherwise you are not calling the constructor of the Character class at all, thus not create a Character object at all (might end up in undefined behavior if you cast the Entity to the derived type, even if it isn't an instance of that object). It is just an example of how it can be used, but it has it's pitfalls described in the link I added to the post.

Comment: Yeah I've seen it, the undefined method. Thanks for your help.